# syntax error, unexpected '}' in php

Tags: php

```
if (is_numeric($fname))
    {
        $Name = "Name can not be numeric";
            $Check=false;
                {
                $length = strlen(utf8_decode($s));
                $utf8 = "12"

                }//line 37, syntax error

    }
```

It says  syntax error, unexpected '}'  in  line 37 which is basically

Comment: semicolon after `$utf8 = "12"`

Comment: Why do you have brackets there anyway?

Comment: I never wrote code helping a friend out

Comment: All sorted thanks  for the help guys.